# Matrix that needs to be reduced to reduced row echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

[image]

What does the first column mean? Do I move the first column to the last column?

Comment: do you know how does reduced row echelon form look like?

Comment: What is the meaning of `...that following...`? Is there a given matrix before the above matrix? And is this shown matrix the reduced form of it?

Comment: do not swap colonms just reduce that the leading ones lie to the right of the previous leading one in the row above